# Metro app working properly when deployed in windows 8 desktop machine & emulator, but not working properly on surface RT Tablet?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-rt

i am developing a C#/XAML windows 8 Metro app,

The application works properly on a Windows 8 machine and emulator, but not on the Surface RT tablet. For example, I have a combobox in one of my screens and I bind the data to the combobox and  set a default item by

```
combobox.selectedItem = "some test";
```

This data appears in the Windows 8 desktop machine and emulator, but the combobox is showing empty on a Surface RT tablet.

Does the combobox control have any problem on a Windows RT tablet?

I a used AnyCPU Configuration, built in Release mode and tested that package on the device which is generated. For the Surface RT do I need to generate an ARM build?

Comment: How are you testing on a Surface RT?

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to answer this problem. I would guess that whatever source you use to populate your combo boxes is not accessible from the devices. If it's some sort of file on your computer, that won't work and you need to send it over as a resource. If it's a service call, you may have an authentication issue.

You might try it from a different desktop machine if one is available. This may or may not confirm my guesses.